# Prove/Disprove if $f(x)>0$ then the limit $>0$

Tags: limits

Prove/Disprove 
that If $f(x) > 0$ for every $x \in \mathbb R$ and $\lim_{x\to x_0} f(x) = L$.
then $L > 0$.

My attempt:
disprove with $|\frac{x-1}{x}|$ however I've noticed that $f(x) = 0$ exists and that cannot be. thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the function $f(x)=\sqrt {|x|}$  for $x\ne 0$ and $f(0)=1$

You see the limit at zero is zero while the values are all positive